# Prove that $p\in[144,\frac{8^4}{27}]$ where $p=(8-x)(8-y)(8-z)$

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

If the sum and the product of three positive numbers $x,y,z$ be respectively 8 and 18 then prove that $p\in[144,\frac{8^4}{27}]$ where $p=(8-x)(8-y)(8-z)$.

I got the max value of $p$ by AM-GM inequality but could not get minimum value.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x+y+z=8$, we have:
$$
p=(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\ge(2\sqrt{xy})(2\sqrt{yz})(2\sqrt{zx})=8xyz=144
$$
Since $xyz=18$.

But note, that the lower and upper bound cannot be achieved, because both require $x=y=z$ which implies $x=2$ and $x=18^{\frac{1}{3}}$ at the same time.

Comment: Well done :-) +1